# How can I tell, in the browser, that my s3 operation has completed and the state of my bucket is consistent?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3

Using the AWS SDK from typescript (please excuse the code, it's still in development):

In my Angular2 service:

```
return this.bucket.deleteObject(params).promise();
```

In my component:

```
this.uploadService.delete(key).then(/*returns before bucket is consistent, listing its contents still shows the deleted item for a few seconds);
```

How can I keep my UI consistent with the state of the S3 bucket? Do I have to poll it for a few seconds afterward and show some kind of progress indicator?

Answer (score 1):

Hey had a quick look at how you are accessing the promise. I dont think you need .promise() in the service. Have you tried it like this:

```
export class TestComponent
{
    private key = 'something';

    constructor(private uploadService: UploadService)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.uploadService
            .delete(this.key)
            .then((err, data) =>
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
    }
}

export class UploadService
{
    delete(params)
    {
        return this.bucket.deleteObject(params);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried about everything. I also have `PUT` and list functions that have the same problem. Even if I immediately call `list()` it's not displaying the data consistently. The only thing that seems to work is an indeterminate timeout of around 2-3 seconds. What I want is a notification or polling strategy that will tell me when my bucket has the contents the user who just performed the operation expects it to have

Comment: I would guess that its just an issue with the way s3 works and takes a bit of time to update. You might have to get bit creative how you keep you local data in sync with s3. In your service after each action such as deleting stuff rather than returning that response create a new request to list the data and wrap it in a timeout. Seems a bit hacky but would guess that's just the way s3 works. Its not really a high performance data base.

Comment: Was just wondering if anyone had used, say, a lambda to publish an event on a pusher.js channel, or monitored an SNS queue. For now, a 2-second timeout seems to do the trick...